# Redirect for default case in React using Switch and BrowserRouter

Tags: reactjs, react-router, switch-statement, frontend

This is my current App.js file in react. What I am trying to achieve is everytime a link of the first switch is accessed, i do not want the navbar to be shown, but otherwise, the navbar has to be visible. I do not have a default case, so I am stuck. If this may help anyone, if the user is already logged in, accessing login/logout directly redirects you to home and if he is not logged in, accessing any other page redirects you to the login page. It would be very helpful if you have a workaround.

```
<BrowserRouter>
  <Switch>
    <Route path='/user/register' component={Register} />
    <Route path='/user/login' component={Login} />
    <Route path='/user/logout' component={Logout} />
    <Navbar />
  </Switch>
  <Switch>  
    <Route path='/note/new' component={NewNote} />
    <Route path='/list/new' component={NewList} />
    <Route path='/note/:noteid' component={NoteDetail} />
    <Route path='/list/:listid' component={ListDetail} />
    <Route path='/home' component={Home} />
    <Route path='/archive' component={Archive} />
    <Route path='/note' component={Note} />
    <Route path='/list' component={List} />
    <Route path='/trash' component={Trash} />
  </Switch>
</BrowserRouter>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Switch](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Switch) isn't a conventional programming "switch" statement, there isn't a "default" case. It simply returns the first matching `Route` or `Redirect` child component. As written though, if none of the `/user/XXX` paths match ***it will*** (*should*) render the `Navbar` (maybe depends on react-router-dom version).

In your case it may be better to render the `Navbar` on a `Route`, outside the `Switch`, and specify what paths it can match, i.e. exclude the `/user` path.

```
<BrowserRouter>
  <Route
    path={['/home', '/archive', '/note', '/list', '/trash']}
    component={Navbar}
  />
  <Switch>
    <Route path='/user/register' component={Register} />
    <Route path='/user/login' component={Login} />
    <Route path='/user/logout' component={Logout} />
    <Route path='/note/new' component={NewNote} />
    <Route path='/list/new' component={NewList} />
    <Route path='/note/:noteid' component={NoteDetail} />
    <Route path='/list/:listid' component={ListDetail} />
    <Route path='/home' component={Home} />
    <Route path='/archive' component={Archive} />
    <Route path='/note' component={Note} />
    <Route path='/list' component={List} />
    <Route path='/trash' component={Trash} />
  </Switch>
</BrowserRouter>
```

Comment: Also, i added this just before the closing Switch tag 
<Route component={Home} />

Comment: @melarCoder Sure, a `Route` with no `path` prop will always match.